Deployment issues - wildfly maven plugin bootable jar multi-module project
I have a multi module j2ee application and I am now trying to create a new module that will be an attempt to package a bootable jar together with a wildfly in order to create a smaller, more isolated and less complex deployment artifact. This bootable jar will be triggered by a k8s cronjob and thus only needs to run temporarily and then be shut down after its job is done. Everything has been fine up until now when I am trying to deploy my jar in my bundled wildfly. I have 2 internal modules that I want to have access to from my bootable jar. What I noticed is that I need to use a plugin (maven-assembly or maven-shade) to get my internal modules to be bundled together in my final jar. However both maven-assembly and maven-shade seem to give me the same issue upon deployment:
Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."final-name.jar".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."final-name.jar".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAllGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getParameterizedType(Parameter.java:201)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedParameter.<init>(BackedAnnotatedParameter.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedParameter.of(BackedAnnotatedParameter.java:44)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedParameter.forExecutable(BackedAnnotatedParameter.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedCallable.initParameters(BackedAnnotatedCallable.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedCallable.<init>(BackedAnnotatedCallable.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.<init>(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:29)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedMethod.of(BackedAnnotatedMethod.java:25)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:198)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.computeValue(BackedAnnotatedType.java:191)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$EagerlyInitializedLazyValueHolder.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:191)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType$BackedAnnotatedMethods.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:191)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.<init>(BackedAnnotatedType.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.slim.backed.BackedAnnotatedType.of(BackedAnnotatedType.java:47)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:84)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformClassToBackedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:35)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.WeakLazyValueHolder.get(WeakLazyValueHolder.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getCastValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getBackedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:194)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:247)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(LazyValueHolder.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:247)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(LazyValueHolder.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(LazyValueHolder.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(LazyValueHolder.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(LazyValueHolder.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:232)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:151)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.jlr.EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.of(EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:93)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformSlimAnnotatedTypeToEnhancedAnnotatedType.apply(ClassTransformer.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.lambda$new$0(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder$1.computeValue(LazyValueHolder.java:32)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.util.cache.ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.getValue(ReentrantMapBackedComputingCache.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.getEnhancedAnnotatedType(ClassTransformer.java:251)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createClassBean(BeanDeployer.java:210)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$2.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

Here is my pom-file:
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>happ</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>test-job</artifactId>
<name>Test::Job</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- INTERNAL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>repository</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation=
                                                 "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.test.me.JobExecutor</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>package</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <bootable-jar>true</bootable-jar>
                <bootable-jar-name>test-job-bootable.jar</bootable-jar-name>
                <feature-packs>
                    <feature-pack>
                        <location>wildfly@maven(org.jboss.universe:community-universe)#22.0.1.Final</location>
                    </feature-pack>
                </feature-packs>
                <packaging-scripts>
                    <packaging-script>
                        <scripts>
                            <script>scripts/wf-ports.cli</script>
                            <script>scripts/add-user.cli</script>
                            <script>scripts/add-driver.cli</script>
                            <script>scripts/add-datasource-node.cli</script>
                        </scripts>
                    </packaging-script>
                </packaging-scripts>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

Here is my startup class:
import com.test.me.entity.TestEntity;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class TestJob {

  @Inject
  TestDao testDao;

  @PostConstruct
  public void onStartup() {

    TestEntity testEntity = testDao.getById(101L);

    System.out.println("ENTITY WITH ID: " + testEntity.getId());
    System.out.println("ENTITY WITH CURRENT VERSION ID: " + testEntity.getCurrentVersion().getId());
  }
}

I have a beans.xml (bean discovery mode = all) and persistence.xml in the resources folder.
If I run without maven shade or maven assembly plugins everything works fine but I dont get my internal modules packaged within my jar which is an issue. The exception doesn't really help me, anyone got any ideas?
Update 29/10
Changing the packaging to war seems to have made a difference and now I am no longer seeing the arrayIndex exception. Now my issue is that persistence.xml is not able to locate my entity classes unless i specify the full path to it via <class>.
Persistence.xml is placed under src/main/java/resource/META-INF. Looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestPU">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/test</jta-data-source>
<!--        <class>com.test.me.entity.TestEntity</class>-->
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="10"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Output from running jar tf target/application-test.war:

META-INF/

WEB-INF/

WEB-INF/classes/

WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/


WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml

WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/version.properties

WEB-INF/classes/se/

WEB-INF/classes/se/tvv/

WEB-INF/classes/se/tvv/nyps/

WEB-INF/classes/se/tvv/nyps/JobExecutor.class

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/com/

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/com/oracle/

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/com/oracle/ojdbc11/

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/com/oracle/ojdbc11/main/

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/com/oracle/ojdbc11/main/module.xml

WEB-INF/classes/wildfly-modules/com/oracle/ojdbc11/main/ojdbc11-
21.5.0.0.jar

WEB-INF/lib/

WEB-INF/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar

WEB-INF/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar

WEB-INF/lib/annotations-2.0.1.jar

**WEB-INF/lib/common.jar**

**WEB-INF/lib/repository.jar**

**com/test/me/entity/TestEntity.class**```

As you can see the entity class is listed as is the repository jar that it comes from.


I don't think bootable jar is designed to support multiple deployments

@ehsavoie what do you mean by multiple deployments, it’s one jar being deployed. I want it to be packeged together with the 2 other internal modules listed as dependencies.

I'd need to look at the details, but I think your packaging type needs to be a war, not a jar if you want to include other resources.

@JamesR.Perkins .war works far better and the issue I get now is that my persistence.xml is having a hard time locating my entity classes that come from one of the internal modules that I have bundled in my war-file. Why is it that .war works better? Any ideas as to why my persistence.xml is having issues finding my entities even though I can see them bundled in my .war when running a jar tf? If i specify the full path in my persistence.xml it works fine but shouldn't have to do that `import com.test.me.entity.TestEntity.

A WAR works because the bootable JAR provisions a server, adds the deployment, then zips it all up into a JAR. A WAR is a web archive for Jakarta EE and typically is the way to go. As to why your entity classes aren't being found, that depends. Does the JAR end up in the WAR.war/WEB-INF/lib?
